# Cascade deleting a model configured at runtime with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

In order to implement a rudimentary revision history system, I  have defined a handful of `Action` entities that are configured with reflection and included in EF Core's ModelBuilder. Each action is treated as a separate entity and contains foreign keys to their corresponding entities.

For instance:

```
public interface IAction
{
  public long Id { get; }
  public long DateTime Date { get; }
  public long CreatorId { get; }
  public User Creator { get; }
}

public interface IPostAction
{
  long PostId { get; }
  Post Post { get; }
}

public interface IUserAction
{
  long UserId { get; }
  User User { get; }
}

public abstract class ActionBase : IAction
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public long CreatorId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey( nameof( CreatorId ) )]
  public User Creator { get; set; }
}

public abstract class PostAction : ActionBase, IPostAction
{
  public long PostId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey( nameof( PostId ) )]
  public Post Post { get; set; }
}

public class AddPostFollowerAction : PostAction, IUserAction
{
  public long UserId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey( nameof( UserId ) )]
  public User User { get; set; }
}
```

These models are then configured by creating a `DynamicAssembly` that defines an IEntityTypeConfiguration for each type.

```
/// <inheritdoc />
   public abstract class ActionConfiguration<TAction> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TAction>
      where TAction : class, IAction
   {

      /// <inheritdoc />
      /// <summary>
      /// Configures the <see cref="IAction" />.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="builder">The configuration builder.</param>
      public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<TAction> builder )
      {
         builder.HasKey( a => a.Id );
         builder.ToTable( $"Actions_{typeof(TAction).Name}" );

         builder.HasOne( a => a.Creator )
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey( a => a.CreatorId );
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Configures the <see cref="IEntity" /> implementation.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="builder">
      /// The configuration builder.
      /// </param>
      public virtual void Configuring( EntityTypeBuilder<TAction> builder )
      {
      }

   }

   /// <summary>
   /// A static cache that auto-generates entity configurations for 
   /// concrete <see cref="IAction"/> classes
   /// </summary>
   public static class ActionConfigurationCache
   {

      #region Data Members

      /// <summary>
      /// The dynamic assembly that stores the auto-generated
      /// <see cref="ActionConfiguration{TAction}"/>s.
      /// </summary>
      public static readonly Assembly Assembly;

      #endregion

      #region Constructor

      /// <summary>
      /// Initializes the cache.
      /// </summary>
      static ActionConfigurationCache()
      {
         Assembly = CreateConfigurationAssembly();
      }

      #endregion

      #region Private Methods

      /// <summary>
      /// Creates a dynamic assembly that stores auto-generated
      /// <see cref="ActionConfiguration{TAction}"/>s.
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns>
      /// The dynamic assembly.
      /// </returns>
      private static Assembly CreateConfigurationAssembly()
      {
         // Gather concrete Action types
         var actionTypes = typeof( IAction ).GetConcreteTypes();

         // Create Dynamic Assembly
         var assemblyName = new AssemblyName( "ActionConfigurationAssembly" );
         var assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly( assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run );

         // Create Dynamic Module
         var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule( "ActionConfigurationCache" );

         // Create ActionConfiguration types
         foreach( var actionType in actionTypes )
            CreateConfigurationClass( module, actionType );

         // Build Assembly
         return assembly;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Creates an entity configuration for the specified <see cref="IAction"/> type
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="module">
      /// The <see cref="Module"/> to define the entity configuration in.
      /// </param>
      /// <param name="type">
      /// A concrete <see cref="IAction"/> implementation to generate an
      /// entity configuration for.
      /// </param>
      /// <returns>
      /// The <see cref="TypeInfo"/> of the generated entity configuration.
      /// </returns>
      private static TypeInfo CreateConfigurationClass( ModuleBuilder module, Type type )
      {
         // Define concrete ActionConfiguration type
         var configGeneric = typeof( ActionConfiguration<> ).MakeGenericType( type );
         var configType = module.DefineType(
            $"{type.Name}Configuration",
            TypeAttributes.Class,
            configGeneric );

         // Create the type.
         configType.CreateTypeInfo();
         return configType;
      }

      #endregion

   }
```

This approach works fine up until entities are deleted. If a post is deleted, it throws a foreign key error due to the way the navigation entities are set up in the `Action` classes. Since they are using the `ForeignKeyAttribute`, `AddPostFollowerAction` is designated as the dependent entity, and `Post` is designated as the principle entity. Thus, when attempting a cascade delete, since the roles are essentially switched, the cascade delete does not remove any of the `Action` entities and causes a constraint violation.

Due to the amount of `Action` entities that will be defined (and more being added in the future due to feature creep) and the fact that EntityFramework does not support polymorphism in this manner, defining a navigation property for each individual `Action` in its corresponding entities is not really feasible.

Is there a way I can configure a cascade delete to remove these actions automatically?

Comment: Cascade delete direction is from principal to dependent, i.e. deleting the principal deletes the dependents. So the roles are not switched and deleting `Post` should delete Post Actions. The problem seems to be different - you have multiple cascade paths from `User` to `Action` and `User` to `PostAction` / `UserAction`, which prevents enabling cascade delete for these relationships.

Comment: @IvanStoev Given the way it is currently set up, is there a way to streamline the cascade path so that it would properly work, or is that something I will have to handle manually for each `Action`?

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, the delete cascade from entity to action entity should already work with your setup. Are you using migrations? Check the generated migrations, the FKs from action entities to corresponding entities should be with cascade delete ON. Make sure this is reflected in the database as well. The only problematic FK relationships should be for `CreatorId`, `UserId` and `PostId`. For these the cascade delete must be turned off and the deletion of `User` must be handled manually or via database trigger.